# inner product space and polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \mathrm{span}\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ be a real inner product space with the
inner product defined by 
$$
\langle f,g\rangle =\int\limits_{-1}^{1} fg 
$$

Check that $T(f) = f(0)$ is a linear functional on this space and find the element of $V$ which represents it (corresponds to).

So how should I do it? From where to begin?

I am guessing the first part is easy because I have to prove that

$$T(f+g)=(f+g)(0)=f(0)+g(0)=T(f)+T(g)$$

and that

$$T(af)=af(0)=aT(f)$$

but what about this vector that I need to find?

I know that it has something to do with Gram-Schmidt but I do not know how.

Comment: The inner product isn't related *at all* with the first part of the question (to prove $\,T\,$ is a l.f.), but what does it mean "to find an element which _represents_it"? Do you man $\,u\in V\,$ s.t. $\,Tw=\langle u,w\rangle\, \;\forall\,w\in V$ (Riesz Rep. Theorem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, in order to prove that $T[f] = f(0)$ is a linear functional you just need to check the two conditions of linearity, ie.
$$T[f + g] = (f + g)(0) = f(0) + g(0) = T[f] + T[g]$$ and
$$T[af] = af(0) = aT[f]\qquad \forall a \in K = \mathbb{R}\ \text{or}\ \mathbb{C}.$$

Now you are asked to find an element representing a linear functional, therefore I suppose you are asked to use the Riesz Representation Theorem. This is what I am talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem.

Roughly speaking, you are asked to look for the vector $g$ satisfying the equality
$$Tf = (f,g).$$

Before doing this just a couple of observations:

$1)$ I suppressed the notation [] as is usually done with linear operators.

$2)$ I am assuming that the field is $\mathbb{R}$ only because there is no conjugacy in the integral defining the inner product.

$3)$ The existence of such a $g$ is given by the above Theorem by Riesz. (It is also unique!)

Finally the problem is just a matter of calculations: let $$g = a x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d.$$ It is determined if we determine its coefficients. To do this just remember that the integral of an odd function over an interval symmetric with respect to the origin equals $0$ and it is two times the integral on the positive subinterval if the function is even. In formulas, if $f(x) = -f(-x)$ then $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx = 0$, while if $f(x) = f(-x)$ we have $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx = 2\int_0^1f(x)dx$.

Now let's compute $\int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)dx$ for some (non-random) $f$.
If f$(x) = 1$ then we impose
$$1 = f(0) = Tf = \int_{-1}^1(a x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d)dx = 2\int_0^1(bx^2 + d)dx = \frac{2}{3}b + 2d.$$
If $f(x) = x^2$ then we impose
$$0 = f(0) = Tf = \int_{-1}^1(ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2)dx = 2\int_0^1(bx^4 + dx^2)dx = \frac{2}{5}b + \frac{2}{3}d$$
If can now find $b$, $d$ by solving the system
$$1 = \frac{2}{3}b + 2d$$
$$0 = \frac{2}{5}b + \frac{2}{3}d.$$

You now you should be able to continue by yourself, and you should also have an idea of what could be nice choises for $f$ to find $a$ and $c$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Using Riesz in this case is way overkill. In the case a a finite-dimensional inner product space, the mapping
$$E \rightarrow E^*$$
$$x \mapsto (t \mapsto (x,t))$$
Is always trivially an isomorphism (it's injective).

Comment: Yes it, anyway the OP can skip whatever he/she doesn't know and the answer still has a point, I guess :D

Comment: @user01123581321345589144... Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Find an orthonormal basis for $\,V\,$ using Gram-Schmidt, say the basis $\,\{u_1,...,u_4\}\,$ you get by applying G-S to the given basis of $\,V\,$ . From here, you get that any element $\,w\in V\,$ has a representation (I'm copying (one of) the proof(s) of Riesz Representation Theorem):

$$w=\sum_{k=1}^4\langle w,u_i\rangle u_i\implies Tw=\sum_{k=1}^4\langle w,u_1\rangle Tu_i=\sum_{k=1}^4\langle w,T(u_i)\,u_i\rangle u_i$$

Well, define now

$$u:=\sum_{k=1}^4 T(u_i)\,u_i\;\ldots\ldots$$