# Finding a polynomial that satisfies a given inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

**Questions**

$V=\Bbb C_n[x],  \langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1 \bar f g $. Find $q_1, q_{-1} \in V$ s.t $\langle q_{\pm 1},f\rangle =f(\pm 1)$. (I'm supposed to find a system of linear equations for those)...

**What I did**
I found this [inner product space and polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394346/inner-product-space-and-polynomial) which was related. 
So I wrote $$q_1=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i,\quad f=\sum_{j=1}^n b_jx^j.$$
Therefore

$$
\begin{align}
\langle q_1,f\rangle & =\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i,\sum_{j=1}^n b_jx^j\right\rangle \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n  a_i \bar b_j\langle x^i,x^j\rangle=
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n  a_i\bar b_j\int_{-1}^1 x^{i+j}\,dx=
\end{align}
$$

From this point I can divide to a case where $i+j$ is odd- then the integral is $0$, if $i+j$ is even the integral is $2$. From here I dont really know how to continue...

Comment: The reason why Donald Knuth invented TeX and why all its descendants like LaTeX and MathJax exist, is so that you could write things like $\langle f,g\rangle$ instead of $<f,g>$.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{C}_n[x]$ mean the space of polynomials of degree $\leqslant n$? Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is that $\;\langle g_{\pm 1},f\rangle=f(\pm1)\;\;\color{red}{\forall\,f\in V}\;$ , then you could do some particular examples:

$$f(x)=c=\text{ a constant}\neq0\implies \langle g_{\pm1},c\rangle:=\int\limits_{-1}^1\overline{g_{\pm1}(x)}c\,dx=c\int\limits_{-1}^1\overline{g_{\pm1}(x)}\,dx$$

So it must be that

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1\overline{g_{\pm1}(x)}=1$$

Or with $\;f(x)=x\;$ :

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1\overline{g_{\pm1}(x)}\,x\,dx=\pm1$$

Deduce the problem has no solution.

If you meant something else then write it clearly.

Comment: edited the question a bit

Comment: As long as you say nothing about $\;f\;$ in the first line chances are many (I'd say most) mathematicians will understand "for all polynomials $\;f(x)\;$", and then  my solution above remains valid, imo.